# Java streams and multiline records

Tags: java, text, stream

I'm trying to use Java streams to read a text file with multi line records

I've got a text file consisting of records, with each record being on 1 or more lines, separated by blank lines.  I'm trying to generate records using Java streams and having issues

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Jstream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Jstream().run(args);
    }

    private void run(String[] args) {
        String input = (args.length == 0) ? "test.in" : args[0];

        try 
        {
            Path path = Paths.get(input);
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(input);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter("^\\s*$");

            Stream<String> streamOfRecords = StreamSupport.stream(
                    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(scanner,
                            Spliterator.ORDERED), false);

            List<String> result =
                streamOfRecords
                    .map(l -> l.replaceAll("\n", " "))
                    .map(l -> l.replaceAll("\r", " "))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for(String s : result)
                System.out.println("-> " + s);

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Input could be

```
this is
a
single record

here is the next record followed by a line with just a space

finally
our
last
record
```

I'd like to see something like

```
-> this is a single record
-> here is the next record followed by a line with just a space
-> finally our last record
```

I don't care how many spaces are between words in a record, as long as there is at least 1.  I did get it to work for useDelimiter("\n\n"), but if the blank line had a space it failed.

Comment: `useDelimiter("\\R\\s*\\R")` for a whitespace line as separator. `\\R` as line separator instead of something like `\r?\n` or what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set multi-line mode in your delimiter regex. Without it, `^` and `$` only check for the start and end of the complete text content instead of the start and end of each line.
You can set multi-line mode with the `(?m)`-flag at the beginning of the regex statement.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter("(?m)^\\s*$");
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner!  That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)) {

      List<String> lines = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
      String[] pLines = lines.stream()
          .reduce("", (line1, line2) -> line2.isEmpty() ? line1 + "#" + line2 : line1 + " " + line2)
          .split("#");

      Arrays.asList(pLines).stream().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```